# Datatable - custom styles for table

Tags: jquery, css, database, datatables, export-to-pdf

I am using **datatable**. I am exporting `table` in pdf. How do I apply custom styles for `table` exported in pdf?

Here's my code :

```
table = $(tableId).DataTable({
            dom: 'frtip',
            ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
            ordering: false,
            searching:false,
            buttons: [
              {
                 extend: 'collection',
                 text: 'Export',
                 buttons: [ {
                     extend: 'pdf',
                     filename : fileName,
                     title : rprtTtl,
                     orientation: "portrait",
                     pageSize : "LETTER",
                     defaultStyle: {
                         margin: 'auto',
                    },
                    customize: function (win) {
                        console.log(win);
                        $(table)
                             .css('margin', 'auto')

                        }
                 },
                 {
                     extend: 'excel',
                     filename : fileName,
                     title : rprtTtl,
                     orientation: "landscape",
                     pageSize : "A3"
                 }]
              }
           ]
        });
```

Actually in pdf my `table` is `aligned left`. I want to `align` the `table` in `center`. How do I apply custom `css` for that?

Comment: Try with inline CSS in table.

Comment: @KajaMydeen But that will change alignment in web page also. I only want to change alignment in exported file.

Comment: Then try with @media rule

Comment: @KajaMydeen I want to set value in options like `customize`. @media rule will be fire on browser events like resize, print etc.